# Embedding prompt engineering suggestions needed. text-embedding-3-large, zero-shot classification

Tags: prompt-design, openai

Model: text-embedding-3-large
dimensions: 2048

---

I want to zeroshot classify Amazon products and which amazon domain you are most likely to find them in.

For the domains, let's imagine I'm using .com, and .co.uk.

America_text = "The United States, US, USA, America, American, Made in the US, Popular in the US", similarly for the UK.

This works OK, but is there any way I can further improve the matching ?